# In python, can you pass variadic arguments after named parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to call instance methods in python 2.7 using both named and variadic arguments?  I like to name parameters for clearer reading of code, but it seems like this code then fails:

```
def function(bob, sally, *args):
    pass

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function(bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally", *values)
```

raises:

```
TypeError: function() got multiple values for argument 'bob'
```

Comment: Fails how?  What is the error?

Comment: `TypeError: function() got multiple values for argument 'bob'`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> can you pass variadic arguments after named parameters?

**Python 3.4.3**: the answer is yes.

You must place the variadic ones first in the function definition

```
def function(*args, bob, sally):
    print(args, bob, sally)

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function(bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally", *values)
function(bob="Hi bob", *values, sally="Hello sally")
function(*values, bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally")
```

produces

```
(1, 2, 3, 4) Hi bob Hello sally
(1, 2, 3, 4) Hi bob Hello sally
(1, 2, 3, 4) Hi bob Hello sally
```

As you can see, you can call the function placing the parameters in any order you prefer.

**Please note:**

the first and second calls above work only if you pass the positional arguments via the `values` iterable, unpacking its contents.

Passing each positional parameter

```
function(bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally", 1, 2, 3, 4)
function(bob="Hi bob", 1, 2, 3, 4, sally="Hello sally")
```

isn't acceptable and produces

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Furthermore, since you explicitly refer to instance methods, it's worth checking what happens if `function` is such a method, say of class `A`

```
class A():
    def function(self, *args, bob, sally):
        print(args, bob, sally)

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a=A()
a.function(bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally", *values)
a.function(*values, bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally")
a.function(bob="Hi bob", *values, sally="Hello sally")
```

still works and produces

```
(1, 2, 3, 4) Hi bob Hello sally
(1, 2, 3, 4) Hi bob Hello sally
(1, 2, 3, 4) Hi bob Hello sally
```

**Python 2.7.6**: the answer is no.

```
>>> def function(*args, bob, sally):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def function(*args, bob, sally):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Another approach could be to give the variadic parameters a name as well

```
values = {'p1': 1, 'p2': 2, 'p3': 3, 'p4': 4}
```

then you could define

```
def function(bob, sally, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['p1'])
```

and call it with

```
function(bob="Hi bob", sally="Hello sally", **values)
```

Comment: The only comment here is the OP says they like naming their parameters, so kwargs would probably be more ideal for this particular case.

Comment: Ah thanks @Pynchia You should put that in your answer too it's a good explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with a slight modification to what you are doing:

```
def foo(bob="abc", sally="def", **kwargs):
    pass

foo(bob="stuff", sally="buff", other_stuff=[1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: except now you have to do `args = kwargs['other_stuff']`

Comment: Agreed but OP said they like naming parameters.